# github как сделать копию репозитория?

Tags: github

Можно ли через визуальный интейрфейс гитхаба сделать кеопию репозитория, чтобы я снес туда свои изменения для себя. Пулреквесты будут только для моего репозитория.
Форком пробовал, но не получилось.

Comment: Так и что не получилось?

Comment: Сделай бранчем, как нормальные люди)